# bufferData - usage parameter differences

Tags: webgl

While reading specification at Khronos, I found:

```
bufferData(ulong target, Object data, ulong usage)
```

'usage' parameter can be: STREAM_DRAW, STATIC_DRAW or DYNAMIC_DRAW

My question is, which one should I use?
What are the advantages, what are the differences?
Why would I choose to use some other instead STATIC_DRAW?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For 'desktop' OpenGL, there is a good explanation here:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object

Basically, usage parameter ***is a hint*** to OpenGL/WebGL on how you intend to use the buffer. The OpenGL/WebGL can then optimize the buffer depending on your hint.

The [OpenGL ***ES*** docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) writes the following, which is not exactly the same as for OpenGL (remember that WebGL is inherited from OpenGL ***ES***):

STREAM

- The data store contents will be modified once and used at most a few times.

STATIC

- The data store contents will be modified once and used many times.

DYNAMIC

- The data store contents will be modified repeatedly and used many times.

The nature of access must be:

DRAW

- The data store contents are modified by the application, and used as the source for GL drawing and image specification commands.

The most common usage is STATIC_DRAW (for static geometry), but I have recently created a small particle system where DYNAMIC_DRAW makes more sense (the particles are stored in a single buffer, where parts of the buffer is updated when particles are emitted).

http://jsfiddle.net/mortennobel/YHMQZ/

Code snippet:

```
function createVertexBufferObject(){
    particleBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, particleBuffer);
    var vertices = new Float32Array(vertexBufferSize * particleSize);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    bindAttributes();
}

function emitParticle(x,y,velocityX, velocityY){
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, particleBuffer);
    // ...
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, particleId*particleSize*sizeOfFloat, data);
    particleId = (particleId +1 )%vertexBufferSize;
}
```

Comment: If set something as DYNAMIC_DRAW, how would I do 'updating' of the buffer? Without updating, the steps are: create buffer, bind it, bufferData, send it to shader program. Where updating comes in place?

Comment: After you have created the buffer and filled it with initial values using gl.bufferData, you can update the buffer (or part of it) in another frame using the gl.bufferSubData function. Try to take a look at the source code of the fiddle - it should be fairly easy to see what's going on.

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone looking at this answer, if you have a look at the link to the documentation, you'll see that stream draw is actually if you modify and use frequently. Not that you modify only once.

Comment: @Ellie note that the first link is to the OpenGL explanation, not OpenGL ***ES*** (WebGL). They seem to differ

Comment: @Ciprian Tomoiaga I was actually refering to the second link, but as you say, gl and gles seem to have their few differences every here and there.