# Efficiently draw dynamic objects

Tags: c++, opengl

What is the best approach to draw dynamic moving objects on OpenGL?

Currently, I'm doing it like the following: I have a class `Actor`, in which constructor I generate a buffer:

```
Actor::Actor(float x, float y): xpos(x),
                                ypos(y),
                                width(1),
                                height(1) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
}
```

All the other processing is done in *every frame*:

```
for(auto const &a: actors) {

    float x =  (a.xpos / tiles_x) * 2 - 1.0f + (1 / tiles_x);
    float y = -((a.ypos / tiles_y) * 2 - 1.0f + (1 / tiles_y));
    float w = a.width / (tiles_x);
    float h = a.height / (tiles_y);

    const GLfloat vertex[] {
        x - w, y - h, 1.0f,
        x - w, y + h, 1.0f,
        x + w, y + h, 1.0f,
        x - w, y - h, 1.0f,
        x + w, y - h, 1.0f,
        x + w, y + h, 1.0f,

    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, a.buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,
                          3,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          0,
                          (void*)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

I am not a OpenGL expert, but it seems to me like pretty inefficient. Isn't there another, more efficient method for this?

Comment: What is a "dynamic moving object"?

Comment: @NicolBolas What I want to say with that is objects that change position regularly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deprecated way would be to use glTransform. The better way would be to use shaders.

You really don't need to send all the vertices to the gpu every frame. You're correct in your assumptions that it is inefficient. When you create your actor, you create the mesh once and send all the vertices to the graphics card. Then every draw frame, all you have to do is bind the buffer and call glDrawArrays. [Something like this.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1377833&seqNum=8)

To apply transformations, you send the x,y,z offsets to the vertex shader and multiply it against the vertices. [This site offers](http://open.gl) some excellent tutorials of how to do this with non-deprecated opengl functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you transform vertices all in the same way you only pass uniform variable of the 4x4 transformation matrix, that is re-calculated per-frame.

If you need to change vertices independently then you must change attribute array and upload it in every frame, but then you should consider using option `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`. See [bufferData - usage parameter differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462517/bufferdata-usage-parameter-differences) for a bit more clarification.

Hope this helps.