# Best way to plot an updating webGL mesh/surface

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

I need to create a surface or mesh (or particle system) in WebGL which updates with a new row at a given time interval. This is essentially a spectral display (similar to a waterfall, but it needs to be in 3D) in which every 2 seconds, the display needs to add an additional column of spectral information. I want this to gradually grow into a surface with coloured vertices/faces/particles based on the relative height as compared to the overall maximum height.

All in all, a very simple endeavour I'd think. Yet I struggle to locate what type of geometry to best use for this also for performance reasons. Ultimately, there are as many as ~1000x1000 points making up a surface, and there are at least 2 such surfaces in the scene at one time.

Options I have played around with thus far include:

- Using a BufferedGeometry with a particle system material. This seems to perform best, but I can't find an elegant way to update this in real time. So when updating it, the entire scene locks up.
- Using a mesh. But there's no simple way to add a row of points and triangulate the whole geometry, make faces etc. in real time. This again either blocks up or the helper triangulation function chokes (randomly it seems).
- Using a PlaneGeometry default set to 1000x1000 in size, and then modifying each point as the data columns are received. I haven't actually tried this yet… but it's crossed my mind as an (undesirable) option.

Neither of the first two options I've tried however perform as nicely as what I need them to. Every 2 seconds, ~1000 points in a row are received and need to be added to the (existing) geometry. Is that really such a complex endeavour? Any hints greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for streaming vertex buffers.

When creating the buffer, you can specify "how" it will be used ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462517/bufferdata-usage-parameter-differences)).

I believe that `STREAM_DRAW` would suit your needs the best.

So, you gradually receive the date, and update only the parts of the buffer that you need to (`gl.bufferSubData` etc), and this parameter will optimize certain things for you.

~2M points shouldn't be a problem on some newer GPU.

Tutorial:

Animating million letters with Three.js -> [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/) (but without streaming).

Comment: thanks, streaming vertex buffers is indeed what I was looking for. Still trying to locate more complete samples than the ones you have provided, but thanks for getting me started on what looks to be the right track!

Comment: Googling 'opengl streaming buffers' will give you plenty resources to read/learn from, but you'll need to take care about ogl versions, if it's possible to write that code in the webGL. Good luck!