# unexpected screen clearing WebGL

Tags: javascript, timeout, webgl

Good day! I need a help with webgl!
According to http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_fundamentals/#disqus_thread
tutorial, I created simple demo of my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/kurz/o2116mz2/1/.

1) Draw first black rect in main task queue

```
drawRect(10, 10, 20, 20);
```

2) Try to draw same rect in timeout and the whole scene will be cleared and only after that the rect is drawing.

```
setTimeout(function(){drawRect(30, 30, 20, 20);}, 1000);
```

My question is how to avoid screen clearing when draw method using timers. In other words I want to see both rects in this example!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are using gl.bufferData() which is actually replacing your scene's content.

You should instead use gl.bufferSubData().

check out this answer [bufferData - usage parameter differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462517/bufferdata-usage-parameter-differences)