# Why can't I delay my gl.drawArrays function in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

In my main function I have the following code to draw three points:

**Working:**

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    gl.vertexAttrib3f(vPosition, vertices[i * 2], vertices[i * 2 + 1], 0.0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 1, 1);
  }
```

This draws three points from an array of vertex points.

Now, when I use almost the same code, but a `setTimeout` to delay the loop (so that each point would be drawn three seconds apart), nothing is drawn.  I have put in a `console.log` and checked that the loop is indeed running, just nothing is being drawn.

**Not Working:**

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout (function () {
      gl.vertexAttrib3f(vPosition, vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], 0.0);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, i, 1);
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }, 3000 * i );
  }
```

Any idea why this would not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with WebGL.  It has to do with how javascript treats `i` in a timeout loop.

By the time the anonymous function inn the `setTimeout` gets called, `i` is already 2.  The solution I used is to create a closure so that `i` retains the value it had in the loop when the `setTimeout` function was called.  The correct, and working code, looks like this:

```
  for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    (function (i) {
      setTimeout (function () {
        gl.vertexAttrib3f(vPosition, vertices[i * 2], vertices[i * 2 + 1], 0.0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, i, 1);
      }, 1000 * (i + 1));      
    })(index);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you clear after draw in timeout!
If it just a mistake - try my question that I asked few days ago: [unexpected screen clearing WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818876/unexpected-screen-clearing-webgl)

Comment: Removing `gl.clear` just gives me `GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0`