# Draw each pixel separately WebGL

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, pixel

First of all, let me talk about my target. I'm creating another one pixel art online editor and decide to make it with WebGL only (no Canvas2D at all). Pretty stupid of me because I have no knowledge in this technology, but I'm trying! So... the question: how to change the color of the only one pixel? I has struggled with another of my "misunderstand" and found this answer with particle system:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16465343/4458277

and I rewrote it to make it appear close to my case:

https://jsfiddle.net/kurz/rt2n7hmb/1/

As you can see, there are 10 pixels with equal colour when you draw on canvas.
Here the main draw method:

```
function mouseMoveEvent(e) {
    /*... detect x and y...*/
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, particleBuffer);
    var data = new Float32Array(2);
    data[0] = x;
    data[1] = y;
    gl.uniform4f(
        gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "color"),
        Math.random(),
        Math.random(),
        Math.random(),
        1.0
    );
    gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, particleId * particleSize * sizeOfFloat, data);
    particleId = (particleId + 1) % vertexBufferSize;
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, vertexBufferSize);
}
```

So how to change this example to the pixels drawn each with a unique color?

Some of you probably say: "use canvas2d!". - No! I think that the future is not canvas2d.
"So use library!". - No, again! For that "simple" thing like draw squares I don't want include large library.

Thank you!

Comment: WebGL is for 3D, use Canvas :-P. I respect your choice to use whatever you want. But it does equal to saying "I will not use a hammer to hammer this nail, I will use my truck to do it because thats what I decided to do"

Comment: But there are lot of awesome 2d graphic engines based on WebGL! (Pixi.js)

Comment: Still you want to do an "Online pixel art editor", then why not use canvas? It has alot of good features for you (Export jpg,png etc, easy 2d drawing etc). It has more support as well.

Comment: WebGL is just fine for 2D. WebGL is not for 3D. WebGL is a rasterizing engine. You do what you want with it. This entire webpage is rendered in OpenGL ES 2.0 if you're in Chrome. The same tech that WebGL is based on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to understand about that code which you posted is that it is passing a variable to the fragment shader, it is not doing any drawing. The fragment shader is doing the drawing.

OpenGL is a tool to manipulate different stages of the rendering process on modern graphics cards. It does not try to cover the use case of blitting pixels to the screen buffer. (`glDrawPixels` was deprecated and is not available in ES 2.0 or WebGL)

However there are ways that you could use it in your application.

I recommend [these](https://open.gl/drawing) two [articles](https://open.gl/textures) to understand the prerequisites, although you should be aware it is intended for openGL 3.2 and C++, not WebGL and Javascript. So you can ignore things such as context creation, the way in which textures are loaded and you don't have to create VertexArrays.

**WebGL solution 1:**

- Create an empty texture.
- Every frame, Draw a quad to the screen which displays this texture.
- On mouse clicks, call `glTexSubImage2D` to modify 1 pixel within the texture.

**WebGL solution 2:**

- Change `gl_PointSize` (Vertex shader line 8)
- Only draw 1 point
- Don't clear the screen (javascript line 45)
- Preserve the webGL screen buffer (javascript lines 86 or 89)

[See modified source](https://jsfiddle.net/m254g3fj/)

*This solution is not modifying 1 exact pixel, I think Solution 1 is a better way to do it*

**Why you should use Canvas2D:**

It is a mistake to consider to Canvas2D is inferior to WebGL, One is a screwdriver and the other is hammer. One is great for attaching things with screws the other is great for attaching things with Nails.

Use WebGL when you want to manipulate a 3d render pipeline, use Canvas2D when you want to manipulate raster images.

**TL;DR:**

If you use Canvas2D you can start making the application you want to today with good performance. If you want to use WebGL, you should make an effort to understand the stages of the render pipeline.

Comment: By the way: You can mix both APIs in the same application. A 2d canvas can be used as a texture by a 3d canvas and a 3d canvas can be used as a drawImage input for a 2d canvas.

Comment: But in a webGL canvas, every time you modify the 2d canvas you are using as a texture you will have to send it into GPU memory again.Also, I can't see how you would apply it to this context.

Comment: https://webglfundamentals.org/

Comment: @OwenDelahoy do you mind explaining why you first set the size of the initial `vertices` buffer to `vertexBufferSize * particleSize`, i.e. `10 * 2`, i.e. `20`.  I stumbled on this question while trying to do something similar, and I'm getting `Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call` errors, but I'm not clear on how to determine the initial buffer size.  Shouldn't the buffer size just be `2`, i.e. an x and y coordinate?

Answer (score 3):

The direct answer to your question is that `gl.uniform4f` is a global variable. So you are effectively doing this:

```
var color = randomColor(); // uniform4f call
for each point:
    drawPoint(p.x, p.y,color);
```

You need to change it into this:

```
for each point:
    var color = gl.uniform4f(...);
    drawPoint(p.x, p.y, color);
```

However, I want to note that using a particle system for doing a pixel editor is probably not the way to go. Imagine what happens if the user repeatedly move around the same area, you would have a lot of redundant data. Secondly, how do you (efficiently) support the erase operation? Or Fill?

Eventually, I think you want to move onto using textures. Textures are basically a fancy name for an array of data, but with limitations on its format and what it can contains. However, GPUs can access them really really fast. So what you want to do is draw a quad the same size of screen and give it individual pixel data via a texture to tell it what to draw. Then manipulate the texture data directly when the user does things and redraw.

It is really too long to include how to implement this in webgl, so I suggest following some tutorials on the web. The best one atm for webgl is the [webgl fundamentals](http://webglfundamentals.org/) series. I suggest starting from there.

Answer (score -2):

To modify a single pixel on the canvas using WebGL, you can use the `gl.drawArrays()` method. First, you need to create a buffer with a single vertex that covers the entire canvas. Then, you can set the color of the pixel you want to modify using the `gl.uniform4f()` method. Finally, you can call `gl.drawArrays()` with the `gl.POINTS` argument to draw a single point on the canvas, which will correspond to the pixel you want to modify.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to modify a single pixel at position (10, 10) on the canvas:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

// Create a buffer with a single vertex that covers the entire canvas
const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// Set the color of the pixel to red
const colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_color');
gl.uniform4f(colorLocation, 1, 0, 0, 1);

// Draw a single point at position (10, 10)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 10, 10);
```

Note that this code assumes that you have already created a WebGL program with a vertex shader and a fragment shader, and that you have obtained the location of the `u_color` uniform and the `position` attribute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy